# Using and extending JOOQ generated DAOs with injected DataSource?

Tags: datasource, cdi, dao, jooq

I'm new to JOOQ... The following code seems to work in WildFly 22 but I'm not sure if that is the best way to do things. What is the preferred way to inject WF DataSource to JOOQ DAOs (my extended ones)? Is there a way to avoid doing the ".get()." in the service below and just leave @Resource(...) etc. connection related for the MyCompanyDAO to handle internally?

In other words: companyDAO.get().fetchOneById(id) vs. companyDAO.fetchOneById(id)

```
@Stateless
public class CompanyService extends DefaultCompanyService {

    @Inject
    private MyCompanyDAO companyDAO;

    public Company find(Integer id) {
        return companyDAO.get().fetchOneById(id);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyCompanyDAO extends CompanyDao {

    @Inject
    private MyConnectionProvider cp;

    public CompanyDAO get() { // since cannot use @Resource in dao constructor
        this.configuration().set(cp).set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
        return this;
    }

    // custom code here
}

public class CompanyDao extends DAOImpl<CompanyRecord, tables.pojos.Company, Integer> {
    // jooq generated code here
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/MyDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Connection acquire() throws DataAccessException {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Could not acquire connection.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void release(Connection connection) throws DataAccessException {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Could not release connection.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put initialization logic of `MyCompanyDAO` inside a `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() { 
    this.configuration().set(cp).set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
}
```

This way, you don't need to call get:

```
@Inject
private MyCompanyDAO companyDAO;

public Company find(Integer id) {
    return companyDAO.fetchOneById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using constructor injection instead? The generated `DAO` classes offer a constructor that accepts a `Configuration` precisely for that:

```java
@Stateless
public class MyCompanyDAO extends CompanyDao {

    @Inject
    public MyCompanyDAO (Configuration configuration) {
        super(configuration);
    }
}
```

If for some reason you cannot inject the entire configuration (which I'd recommend), you could still inject the `ConnectionProvider`:

```java
@Stateless
public class MyCompanyDAO extends CompanyDao {

    @Inject
    public MyCompanyDAO (MyConnectionProvider cp) {
        super(DSL.using(cp, SQLDialect.POSTGRES));
    }
}
```